# Give PHP root permissions to files in folder

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am a php novice, getting a hang for things, but have little knowledge of basic security concepts or server administration. I was recently hacked (assuming from mysql injection), and my files were all deleted. After trying to get things back up and running and trying to properly secure my scripts, I ran into this issue:

It was recommended I place all my database connection usernames/passwords, etc in a separate .inc file, in a separate folder (mine unfortunately needs to be in a folder in the root directory). I have done that fine, but it was also recommended I only give 600 permissions to the folder with the connection files.

One of my DB connection files looks like this:

```
$usersusername = "myusername goes here";
$userspassword = "64bit encrypted password goes here";
$usershostname = "localhost";
$usersdbname = "my database goes here";
```

and my include in my index.php looks like this:

```
include_once '/dbauth/myloginscript.inc';
```

and I am yielding the error:

```
Warning: include_once(/home/mycpaneluser/public_html/dbauth/myloginscript.inc): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/mycpaneluser/public_html/index.php on line 60

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/mycpaneluser/public_html/dbauth/myloginscript.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/myloginscript/public_html/index.php on line 60
```

I am told I need to have an inclusion in http.conf to allow permissions somehow, but before I even get that far, am I following the right procedure to protect my DB login info, or am I missing the mark? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check `config.inc.php`.

Comment: Make sure your `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'yourUsername';` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourPassword';`.

Comment: I hope your file is not really `config.inc` it should be `config.inc.php`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'yourUsername';` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourPassword';` in `serverFolder/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Append *.php* to *myloginscript.inc* (file name and the reference to
   it) and add PHP opening tag at the very beginning of the file so it
   will be parsed by php instead of being displayed as plain text. Just
   for worst case if called directly in a browser accessible directory.
2. I assume "root" folder actually is your ftp home directory which on most webhosting environments by default is one level up from your vhost's document root. If you put your inc file in there reference would be `include_once '../myloginscript.inc.php';`
   Check your webhosting's structure and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] var for the correct inclusion path.

Comment: it seems that changing the permissions of the folder /dbauth/ to 770 appears to have worked, without needing to change any http.conf or any other administrative files. my question now is: is this safe enough?

Comment: Better be sure it is working. ;) If yes and the inc file is not accessible by calling it directly within your domain this should be okay. However, do not use plain text files for login credentials, always add .php and enclose php code with php tags.